# The Shi Shi Shi Shi Shi poem?

Tags: pinyin

A while ago I came across this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_Shi_shi_shi_shi

Very interesting.

I wonder if there's any more homophonic poems like this? Or even is there a genre?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers seem to have mistaken what you are looking for...

Wikipedia has a page of **同音文章** (one-syllable articles or homophonic poems (as you called it)): [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E9%9F%B3%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0)

(in case they get deleted here's what they have below)

**侄治痔**

> 《侄治痔》
>
> 芝之稚侄郅，至智，知制纸，知织帜。
>
> 芝痔，炙痔，痔殖，郅至芝址，知之，知芷汁治痔，至芷址执芷枝，豸至，踯，郅执直枝掷之，枝至豸趾，豸止。
>
> 郅执芷枝致芝，芝执芷治痔，痔止。
>
> 芝炙脂雉肢致郅。

**羿裔熠**

> 羿裔熠，邑彝，义医，艺诣。熠姨遗一裔伊，伊仪迤，衣旖，异奕矣。熠意伊矣，易衣以贻伊，伊遗衣，衣异衣以意异熠，熠抑矣。伊驿邑，弋一翳，弈毅，毅仪奕，诣弈，衣异，意逸。毅诣伊，益伊，伊怡，已臆毅矣，毅亦怡伊。翌，伊亦弈毅。毅以蜴贻伊，伊亦贻衣以毅。伊疫，呓毅，癔异矣，倚椅咿咿，毅亦咿咿。毅诣熠，意以熠，议熠医伊，熠懿毅，意役毅逸。毅以熠宜伊，翼逸。熠驿邑以医伊，疑伊胰痍，以蚁医伊，伊遗异，溢，伊咦。熠移伊，刈薏以医，伊益矣。伊忆毅，亦呓毅矣，熠意伊毅已逸，熠意役伊。伊异，噫，缢。熠癔，亦缢。

**遗镒疑医**

> 伊姨殪，遗亿镒。伊诣邑，意医姨疫，一医医伊姨。翌，亿镒遗，疑医，以议医。医以伊疑，缢，以移伊疑。伊倚椅以忆，忆以亿镒遗，以议伊医，亦缢。噫！亦异矣！

**易姨医胰**

> 《易姨医胰》 易姨悒悒，依议诣夷医。医疑胰疫，遗意易姨倚椅，以异仪移姨胰，弋异蚁一亿，胰液溢，蚁殪，胰以医。易胰怡怡，贻医一夷衣。医衣夷衣，怡怡奕奕。噫！以蚁医胰，异矣！以夷衣贻夷医亦宜矣！

**于瑜欲渔**

> 于瑜欲渔，遇余于寓。语余：“余欲渔于渝淤，与余渔渝欤？”余语与瑜：“余欲鬻玉，俞禹欲玉，余欲遇俞于俞寓。”余与于瑜遇俞禹于俞寓，逾俞隅，欲鬻玉于俞，遇雨，雨逾俞宇。余语于瑜：“余欲渔于渝淤，遇雨俞寓，雨逾俞宇，欲渔欤？鬻玉欤？” 于瑜与余御雨于俞寓，俞鬻玉于余禹，雨愈，余与于瑜踽踽逾俞宇，渔于渝淤。

**熙戏犀**

> 西溪犀，喜嬉戏。席熙夕夕携犀徙，席熙细细习洗犀。犀吸溪，戏袭熙。席熙嘻嘻希息戏。惜犀嘶嘶喜袭熙。

**饥鸡集矶记**

> 唧唧鸡，鸡唧唧。几鸡挤挤集矶脊。机极疾，鸡饥极，鸡冀己技击及鲫。机既济蓟畿，鸡计疾机激几鲫。机疾极，鲫极悸，急急挤集矶级际。继即鲫迹极寂寂，继即几鸡既饥，即唧唧。

**狮食豕史**

> 狮识豕，豕识狮。始，狮嗜舐豕；豕适。豕时侍狮食柿，狮适。时逝，狮始试豕势。狮舐豕时，适时试噬豕。狮嗜豕时，豕试噬狮。狮嗜豕时，豕适示狮。豕噬狮 时，狮奭。豕始识狮势实势。豕蓍筮，筮示：狮实誓噬弑豕。豕饰失势，事事适狮。时时侍狮。师事狮。试使狮释豕。 是时，豕视虱噬狮，狮拭虱，狮实失适。豕舐狮时，噬虱示狮。豕时时噬虱示狮，使狮适。狮视豕噬虱，狮释。狮始识豕势实是噬虱，豕失势。狮始矢誓弑豕。适 时，豕适噬虱示狮，狮示豕：豕噬虱失实，豕实是试弑狮。狮始施狮式示豕。豕视狮式，豕失屎。狮始噬弑豕。 狮噬食豕势，豕失势，豕逝世。
>
> 适时，十豕驶适。十豕视豕尸，奭。十豕誓师，誓使狮释豕尸事实。狮释：狮食实是柿，食豕是失实。狮视豕是‘士’，豕视狮是‘师’。狮事事适豕，豕失识世事。豕时拭狮豕屎；时施矢石弑狮。适时狮驶，豕施矢石弑狮失事，豕弑豕，豕逝世。狮饰弑豕事实，十豕释，驶逝。
>
> 豕逝世，狮失豕侍。狮食失柿。狮始试食豕尸。狮食豕尸实适。狮始识豕尸实适狮食。是始，狮时时弑豕，嗜食豕尸。
>
> 始，狮视十豕势似狮。时逝，狮始识，十豕势实似豕。视十豕是十尸。适时，狮视十豕适，狮施狮式示十豕。狮恃势噬弑豕。十豕失是豕，十豕驶逝。 狮拾豕尸适市。使絁饰豕尸。狮视市，示市：狮是豕师，豕师事狮。豕视师失食，豕矢誓使师食豕。豕逝世，侍师食豕尸，豕实是‘士’。狮食豕，狮失‘士’，实 狮蚀。是使狮谥豕：‘豕氏’。谥豕‘仕’。狮示市：十豕师事‘豕士’。
>
> 狮时适市，施狮式示市。诗《狮食豕史诗〉示市：
>
> 狮食实是豕，豕食实是柿。时时狮食豕，世世豕食柿。
>
> 事实是事实，实事是实事。世视狮食豕，实是事实事。

Baidu baike also listed some others: [here](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1756142.htm)

**《对联》**

> 上联：齐妻起棋，齐欺妻气，妻弃七棋。
>
> 下联：伊姨移椅，伊倚姨疑，姨遗一椅。

**【吏李立莅】**

> 吏李立莅，赲逦屴岦峛沥俚黎，立艃漓里叕鲤礼黎，罹沴厉离，俚黎蛎鹂历呖。

**《季姬击鸡记》**

> 季姬寂，集鸡，鸡即棘鸡。棘鸡饥叽，季姬及箕稷济鸡。鸡既济，跻姬笈，季姬忌，急咭鸡，鸡急，继圾几，季姬急，即籍箕击鸡，箕疾击几伎，即齑，鸡叽集几基，季姬急极屐击鸡，鸡既殛，季姬激，即记《季姬击鸡记》。

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this website.

[Tongue Twister Examples and Origin](http://www.chinesetolearn.com/listen-funny-chinese-tongue-twister-rao4-kou3-ling4-%E7%BB%95%E5%8F%A3%E4%BB%A4-chinese-tongue-twister-samples-twisters-pinyin-english-translation-info-twisters-origin-development-coll/)

there are example tongue twisters and the origins of tongue twister are explained (in Chinese).

[Tongue Twister in Chinese](http://raokouling.911cha.com/)

This is another website where examples of tongue twisters are shown only in Chinese. There is no Pinyin for this. I think this is more easier than the one above. The tongue twisters are not that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `Tongue Twister` with Chinese, you can look at [this webpage](http://hua.umf.maine.edu/Chinese/topics/tongue/douying.html),there are many interesting tongue twister examples.